# Join records only on first match

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, left-join, case

im trying to join two tables. I only want the first matching row to be joined the others have to be null.

One of the tables contains daily records per `User` and the second table contains the goal for each user and day.

The joined result table should only join the firs ocurrence of `User` and `Day` and set the others to `null`. The Goal in the joined table can be interpreted as `DailyGoal`.

**Example:**

```
Table1                                 Table2
Id   Day          User    Value        Id  Day          User   Goal
================================       ============================
01   01/01/2020   Bob     100          01  01/01/2020   Bob    300
02   01/01/2020   Bob     150          02  02/01/2020   Carl   170
03   01/01/2020   Bob     50           
04   02/01/2020   Carl    200          
05   02/01/2020   Carl    30    

ResultTable
Day          User   Value   Goal 
============================================
01/01/2020   Bob    100     300
01/01/2020   Bob    150     (null)
01/01/2020   Bob    50      (null)
02/01/2020   Carl   200     170
02/01/2020   Carl   30      (null)
```

I tryed doing top1, distinct, subqueries but I cant find way to do it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option uses window functions:

```
select t1.*, t2.goal
from (
    select t1.*,
        row_number() over(partition  by day, user order by id) as rn
    from table1 t1 
) t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.day = t1.day and t2.user = t1.user and t1.rn = 1
```

A `case` expression is even simpler:

```
select t1.*,
    case when row_number() over(partition  by day, user order by id) = 1
        then t2.goal
    end as goal
from table1 t1
```

Comment: Thanks! I Have no idea what the `partition` syntax means or does but I will study it